# Hibernate positional parameters zero based

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa, parameters

I'm migrating a project from Hibernate 4.2.6 to 5.2.0.

I noticed that for Hibernate 5.2.0, the native queries now require zero based parameter positionning.

According to the [JPA 2.1 Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/persistence-2_1-fr-eval-spec/JavaPersistence.pdf)

> #### 3.10.13 Positional Parameters
>
> Only positional parameter binding and positional access to result items may be portably used for native
>   queries, except for stored procedure queries for which named parameters have been defined. **When
>   binding the values of positional parameters, the numbering starts as “1”.** It is assumed that for native
>   queries the parameters themselves use the SQL syntax (i.e., “?”, rather than “?1”).

My understanding of the specification is that even for native queries, the numbering should start with 1.

Now according to Hibernate documentation of [Query.setParameter(int, Object)](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setParameter-int-java.lang.Object-). 
The position is numbered from 0. In the documentation for Hibernate 4.2 as well as for 5.2.

I made a micro test

#### First with Hibernate 4.2.6

```
@PersistenceContext 
private EntityManager entityManager;


Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from Game g where title = ?");
query.setParameter(1, GAME_TITLES[0]);
List list = query.getResultList();
```

This works with hibernate 4.2.6.

The persistence.xml file looks like this

```
<persistence-unit name="test" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect"/>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

#### The same with Hibernate 5.2

```
Query query = entityManager.createNativeQuery("select * from Game g where title = ?");
query.setParameter(0, GAME_TITLES[0]);
List list = query.getResultList();
```

The only difference is the 0 index in the setParameter.

The persistence.xml is also very similar

```
<persistence-unit name="test">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/arquillian</jta-data-source>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform" />
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

I traced the code in both version. I could find in 4.2.6 where the 1 based index is handeled. I could not find a similar code in version 5.2.

I found a post in the hibernate [forums](https://forums.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1025339&p=2467449&hilit=positional+parameters&sid=dd4339194614f24dda7f6cff7ba1e212#p2467449) dating back to 2009 that:

> Well, only if you use the JPA-Query-Api the first parameter must have index = 1.
>   You are using the Hibernate-Query-Api where the first parameter must have index = 0.

Obvioulsy I'm using JPA. 
So the question is:

Is there a way to configure Hibernate 5.2 to get back the 1 based positional parameter? I would hate to change the code in order not to conform to the specification.

Comment: Your understanding of JPA native query numbered parameters is correct. Start at 1, just like JDBC. If your provider doesn't do this then report a bug

Answer (score 4):

Hibernate 5.2 has merged the `hibernate-entitymanager` module into `hibernate-core`, so this issue might have occurred in this process.

Since Hibernate **5.2.1** fixed this issue, you just have to upgrade to 5.2.1 or a later version.

Comment: Thank you, I opened an issue

Comment: Cross-link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-10885

Comment: Has been fixed for version 5.2.1

Comment: Still present in 5.6.11